# $A$ is similar to a triangular matrix but not $A$ need not be diagonalisable matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries such that $A^m=I$ for some positive integer $m$. then

1) $A$ is diagonalisable matrix.

2) $A$ is similar to a triangular matrix but not $A$ need not be diagonalisable matrix.

3) all the eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of unity.

4) none of the above.

Since $m$ is some positive integer, always not prime. So my thinking says option 2 and 3 are correct. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ satisfies $p(A) = 0$, where $p(x) = x^m - 1$.  Because $p$ has no repeated factors, it must be the case that $A$ is diagonalizable (and each eigenevalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $p(\lambda) = 0$).  So, 1 is correct.

Every matrix is similar to a triangular matrix, $A$ included.  However, $A$ **is** necessarily diagonalisable.  So 2 is incorrect as stated; I suspect that you have copied it incorrectly.

3 is correct.  As I stated in the first paragraph, each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $p(\lambda) = 0$, and hence $\lambda^m = 1$.